# Google Spreadsheets: Script to check for completion of ImportHTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scrape

I am trying to scrape data of a website once day automatically. In Google Spreadsheets, i use the `=ImportHTML()` function to import data tables, and then I extract the relevant data with a `=query()`. These functions take between 10 and 30 seconds to complete calculation, every time I open the spreadsheet.

I use a scheduled Google Apps Script, to copy the data into a different sheet (where it is stored, so i can run statistics) every day.

My problem is that I am having trouble to make the script wait for the calculations to be finished, before the data is copied. The Result is that my script just copies the error Message "N/A".

I tried just adding a `Utilities.sleep(60000);`, but it didn't work.

Is it possible to create a loop, that checks for the calculation to finish? I tried this without success:

```
function checkForError() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = spreadsheet.getRange ("Today!A1");
  if (source = "N/A") {
    Utilities.sleep(6000);
    checkForError();
  } else {
    moveValuesOnly();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Locks are for this. Look up lock services in the docs. Use a public lock.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I used Zig's suggestion (combined with my own check loop) to solve my similar problem:

```
   // Get lock for public shared resourse 
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
   // Wait for up to 120 seconds for other processes to finish.
   lock.waitLock(120000);
   // Load my values below
   //   something like sheet.getRange("A1").setFormula('=  etc...  
   // Now force script to wait until cell D55 set to false (0) before 
   // performing copy / pastes
  var current = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[1]);
  var ready = 1;
  var count = 0;
       while (true) {
        // break out of function if D55 value has changed to zero or counter
        // has hit 250
         if (count >= 250) break;

        // otherwise keep counting...
     ready = current.getRange("D55").getValue();
         if (ready == 0) {count = 400;}
            Utilities.sleep(100);
                   ++count;
      }
  // wait for spreadsheet to finish... sigh...
  Utilities.sleep(200);
  // Do my copy and pastes stuff here
  // for example sheet.getRange("a1:b1").copyTo(sheet.getRange("a3"), {contentsOnly:true});
  // Key cells are updated so release the lock so that other processes can continue.
   lock.releaseLock();
  // end script
   return;
}
```

This has worked fantastic for me, stopped Google's sporadic service from ruining my work!
Thanks goes to Zig's suggestion!